# How to fit Generalized Additive Model with gam() where always all columns are used as predictors (no hard coding part in model fitting)

Tags: datatable, forecasting, gam, forecast, r-colnames

I have a train data table in `R`, which always have different columns, for example now the data table has the following column names:

```
library(mgcv)
dt.train <- c("DE", "DEWind", "DESolar", "DEConsumption", "DETemperature", 
              "DENuclear", "DELignite")
```

Now I want to fit a Generalized Additive Model (= GAM) with integrated smoothness estimation that predicts the `DE` price. At the moment I fit the model as the following:

```
fitModel <- mgcv::gam(DE ~ s(DEWind)+s(DESolar)+s(DEConsumption)+s(DETemperature)+
                           s(DENuclear)+s(DELignite), 
                      data = dt.train)
```

The column names are currently hard-coded, but I don't want to change this all the time, I would like to let the program recognize how many columns there are and fit the model with the existing columns. So, I would like to have something like this (which works for `stats::lm()` or `stats::glm()`):

```
fitModel <- mgcv::gam(DE ~ .-1, data = dt.train)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with `gam()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend you do this for statistical reasons, but…

```r
nms <- c("DE", "DEWind", "DESolar", "DEConsumption", "DETemperature", 
              "DENuclear", "DELignite")
## typically you'd get those names as
## nms <- names(dt.tain)

## identify the response
resp <- 'DE'
## filter out response from `nms`
nms <- nms[nms != resp]
```

Create the right hand side of the formula, by pasting on the `s(` and `)` bits, and concatenating the strings separated by `+`:

```r
rhs <- paste('s(', nms, ')', sep = '', collapse = ' + ')
```

which gives us

```
> rhs
[1] "s(DEWind) + s(DESolar) + s(DEConsumption) + s(DETemperature) + s(DENuclear) + s(DELignite)"
```

Then you can add on the response and `~`:

```r
fml <- paste(resp, '~', rhs, collapse = ' ')
```

which gives

```
> fml
[1] "DE ~ s(DEWind) + s(DESolar) + s(DEConsumption) + s(DETemperature) + s(DENuclear) + s(DELignite)"
```

Finally coerce to a formula object:

```r
fml <- as.formula(fml)
```

which gives

```
> fml
DE ~ s(DEWind) + s(DESolar) + s(DEConsumption) + s(DETemperature) + 
    s(DENuclear) + s(DELignite)
```